# newSeqExpressionSet function troubleshooting in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, normalization

I want to rebuild the Ruvseq model based on the "RUVseq" manual in Bioconductor. But, I can't use these `newSeqExpressionSet`, `plotRLE`, `plotPCA`, and `library(betweenLaneNormalization)`functions. every time it gives: "could not find function newSeqExpressionSet"

I used R 4.2.2 and loaded these libraries:

`library(edgeR)`
`library(RUVSeq)`
`library(EDASeq)`
`library(zebrafishRNASeq)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and include any code you've written so far (even if it results in an error) with your dataset (or an example dataset)?

Comment: You haven't added any data to your post and the only code you've added just loads packages. Can you look at [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to see examples of reproducible examples?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you have not installed the package appropriately. RUVseq has some perquisites, you have to pay attention to warnings and errors after loading the package.